# ClickOnce Fails to Launch After Install

Tags: clickonce

I’m having a problem with my ClickOnce application at work. The application refuses to launch when its icon is clicked. No error is displayed, it just doesn’t load. This is only happening on some deployment machines, not all. As far as I know, all of the machines at work are more-or-less identical ... but I know that often doesn't matter.

The application installs/updates okay -- or appears to. The installation log says everything has installed fine; it’s just when the user tries to launch the application that the problem occurs.

The application DOES launch when I browse to the .exe in the install location (i.e. C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\etc\etc\etc\Application.exe) using the command prompt.

Some details about the non-compliant deployment machines:

- The machines have the correct .NET prerequisites installed.
- They all have the same permissions/firewall settings.
- They are all running (or are trying to run, rather!) the most recent version of the application.
- I have tried reinstalling the application/deleting the 2.0 folder & updating several times.
- There is no Kensington Mouseworks software installed on any of them.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

So, I fixed it ... But not sure how/why this was a fix. Despite the fact that we've disabled UAC on all machines (via the control panel) because we don't want it, I had to make sure that the EnableLUA regkey was set to 1. The thing is, some of the affected PCs already *had* EnableLUA set to 1, so I simply set it to 0, restarted, set it to 1, then restarted again. (Reg path: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System)

Is UAC ever really turned off? And is there a way to turn it off AND have my application run happily at the same time, on all machines?

Comment: ugh .. I am having the same exact issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598558/application-does-not-run-after-being-published-via-clickonce-but-runs-from-folde but I would rather not mess with the registry .. are you saying that running the clickonce from the shortcut runs it the app with different permissions ?